# Backup a sqlite3 database

Tags: database, sqlite, batch-file

I have a Python project where I use sqlite3 to save data.

I want to do a backup of the database ( I am really worried about datalock, cause my software will be used by like 10 peoples which will have to access to my database to write or read, and without luck, someone will try to access to the database at the bad moment, even if I will increase timeout)

If I do it manually with the Windows cmd, there is no problem.

```
v:
cd V:\directory\
sqlite3 mydatabase.db"
.backup backup_db.db
```

I try to do a batch file which will be call every hours by my python software to do it automatically.
I applied the same commands in it.

The batch file is launched, but the process stop after the opening of the database.
The dot command is not executed.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hmm... SQLite is a very nice tool, but concurrent access is not its best point. If you want to be able to securely backup the database while users could read or write it, you'd better use PostgreSQL or MariaDB which are both good at handling concurrent accesses.

Comment: @SergeBallesta SQLite can handle concurrency just fine. Reads are concurrent, writes are queued - which is not a problem unless there are very many writes that are also very slow. But this would cause issues in "larger" databases, too. Backups also work while the database is open: The DB is locked, readers won't notice it at all, writers will have to wait until the backed is done (i.e. "until the DB file is copied") and the database lock is released. For a scenario with 10 or so users and a DB file that is not GBs in size this wont be much of a problem. Certainly no reason to move to Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch files do not work the way you think they do.

You currently think that after the line `sqlite3 "mydatabase.db"` you are in some kind of "database mode" and all the following lines in the batch file are passed to the sqlite3 process.

That's not the case.

Every line in a batch file is executed after the previous like has finished running.

The line `sqlite3 "mydatabase.db"` starts the sqlite3 process... and then waits until this process exits. Which never happens unless you do it manually by pressing a key.

And **after that** cmd.exe will try to execute the command `.backup backup_db.db`, but since that's not a command cmd.exe understands, it will fail with an error (*"'.backup' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*).

What you really want to do is create a script file and pass it to for SQLite for processing. This can be done by

- redirecting a file into the sqlite3 process. Assume that `create_backup.txt` contains the commands to create a backup:

  ```
  sqlite3 "mydatabase.db" < create_backup.txt
  ```
- piping the file into the sqlite3 process, e.g. using `type`:

  ```
  type create_backup.txt | sqlite3 "mydatabase.db"
  ```

  alternatively you can use `echo` to output a command:

  ```
  echo .backup backup_db.db | sqlite3 "mydatabase.db"
  ```

Obviously the `echo` method is easier for one-liners whereas the input redirect with `<` or writing out a file with `type` are easier to for more complex, multi-line operations.

Using the `-init` parameter of `sqlite3.exe` is another option you can try. Check the SQLite documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your advices and solutions, and also for the batch working clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the sqlite3 executable is `sqlite3 [db_file] [command]`.  So, in your batch file, you should include `.backup` on the same line.

```
v:
cd V:\directory\
sqlite3 mydatabase.db ".backup backup_db.db"
```